# BeautifulSoup4 search tag by text regex

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have these 2 scenarios where I want to search a tag by its text using a regular expression.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<B><A NAME="toc96446_13"></A>TEXT </B></P>", "html5lib")
soup.find('b', text=re.compile('TEXT'))
```

I assume this doesn't work because of the  tag inside  which actually contains my TEXT.

Also how can I find a tag containing only digits?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<p>169</p>", "html5lib")
soup.find('p', text=re.compile(r'[0-9]{1,}'))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Fir searching elements you can use `lambda` and `tag.text`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

data = """
<B><A NAME="toc96446_13"></A>TEXT</B></P>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')
print(soup.find(lambda t: t.name=='b' and re.search(r'TEXT', t.text)))
```

Prints:

```
<b><a name="toc96446_13"></a>TEXT</b>
```

For **only** digits, you can leverage `regexp` `^` and `$` constants (note, this will match only first `<p>` tag with `169` inside, not second with `ab1234` inside):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<p>169</p><p>ab1234</p>", 'html5lib')
print(soup.find('p', text=re.compile(r'^\d+$')))
```

Prints:

```
<p>169</p>
```